# CSS styling for height of textarea not working

Tags: css

The default size of the `<textarea>` element is too is small for my use, i tried to customize the height with the following css code:

```
textarea {
    width:400px;
    height:150px;
}
```

The html textarea:

```
<li>
  Body*:<br>
  <textarea name="body"></textarea>
</li>
```

But this won't work. Any solutions ??

P.S: I'm using Mozilla firefox.

Comment: Please share `textarea` HTML..

Comment: Should work, it is working in this fiddle.http://jsfiddle.net/harendra/4K34r/

Comment: it works in [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/R8bsA/), it might be a problem of parent element's `width` , that stop `textarea` to resize, may be you enclosed this textarea in a `table` and defined that `table's width` that stop your `textarea` to resize.

Answer (score 2):

It works fine. See this http://jsfiddle.net/qhqLV/

your html code

```
<li>
  Body*:<br>
  <textarea name="body"></textarea>
</li>
```

your css

```
textarea {
  width:400px;
  height:150px;
}
```

Note:debug the code and check the parent elements width and height.I think that is the issue.May be the textarea accept any other style during execution.